# ¿Cómo visualizar foto en ventana modal?

Tags: javascript, html, modal

Tengo un problema a la hora de presentar la foto visualizándose. El código que está a continuación es una librería en JS plano(No JQuery),la cual sirve para crear ventanas modal. El HTML de las ventanas modal se crear mediante este y me genera un "template". Estoy creando una ventana modal en la cual hay un sistema de subida y viualizacion de fotos.

Hay una función llamada "*function* **m_postfoto**() en donde se aloja ese código del input y la zona donde se visualiza la foto.

Mi problema está en que no se quiere mostrar la foto, me lanza un error en la consola, pero cuando trato de probar ese sistema en una pagina sin usar este código de ventana modal, entonces si funciona.

```js
/**
 * Modal.js
 * @author Joao Teixeira
 * @version 1.0
 * Copyright (c) Joao Teixeira
 * https://github.com/jpntex
 *
 */

var Modal = (function() {
  function Modal(type, options) {

    var defaults = {
      title: '', // modal title
      message: '', // modal message
      autoOpen: true, // show modal when declared
      closeOnEscape: true, // close when escape key pressed
      closeOnBlur: true, // close when overlay is clicked
      animated: true, // animate modal

      // button options
      buttonLbl: 'OK', // main button label
      buttonClass: '', // main button class
      cancelLbl: 'Cancel', // cancel button label

      // callbacks
      onConfirm: function() {}, // callback on confirm
      onCancel: function() {}, // callback on cancel
      onClose: function() {} // callback on close
    };

    this.type = type;
    this.options = extend(defaults, options);

    // animations not supported on IE9
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 9") !== -1) {
      this.options.animated = false;
    }

    this.init();
  }

  // modal templates
  var templates = {
    modal: '<div class="modal-box">' +
      /* '<div class="modal-title">[[title]]<div class="close-modal" data-action="close">&times;</div></div>' +*/
      '<div id="modal-message" class="styles">[[message]]</div>' +
      '<div class="modal-buttons">[[buttons]]</div>' +
      '</div>',
    btn: '<div class="modal-btn" data-action="close">[[label]]</div>',
    btnAlert: '<div class="modal-btn btn-alert" data-action="close">[[label]]</div>',
    btnConfirm: '<div class="modal-btn btn-confirm [[classes]]" data-action="confirm">[[label]]</div>'
  };







  // generates the modal html from the templates given the modal's type and options
  function buildModal(type, options) {
    var modal = document.createElement('div');
    modal.className = 'modal';

    if (options.closeOnBlur) modal.setAttribute('data-action', 'close');

    var modalTmplt = templates.modal;

    // set modal animations
    if (options.animated) {
      modal.className += ' fadeIn';
    }

    modalTmplt = modalTmplt.replace('[[title]]', options.title);
    modalTmplt = modalTmplt.replace('[[message]]', options.message);

    // add buttons based on modal type
    switch (type) {





      case 'foto':
        var buttons = templates.btn.replace('[[label]]', options.cancelLbl);
        buttons += templates.btnConfirm.replace('[[label]]', options.buttonLbl).replace('[[classes]]', options.buttonClass);
        modalTmplt = modalTmplt.replace('[[buttons]]', buttons);

        break;









    }

    modal.innerHTML = modalTmplt;
    return modal;
  }








  // handle modal events
  Modal.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    var dataAction = event.target.getAttribute('data-action');

    // animation ended callback
    if (event.type === 'animationend') {
      return this.onAnimationEnd(event);
    }

    // check if 'Esc' key was pressed and close modal if set
    if (this.options.closeOnEscape) {
      if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        this.options.onCancel();
        return this.close();
      }
    }

    if (dataAction === 'close') {
      this.options.onCancel();
      return this.close();
    }

    if (dataAction === 'confirm') {
      this.options.onConfirm();
      return this.close();
    }
  };

  // animation end event handler
  Modal.prototype.onAnimationEnd = function(event) {
    this.modal.removeEventListener('animationend', this);
    document.body.removeChild(this.modal);
    this.options.onClose();
    return this;
  };

  // initialize modal creation
  Modal.prototype.init = function() {
    this.modal = buildModal(this.type, this.options);
    if (this.options.autoOpen) this.open();
  };

  // open modal
  Modal.prototype.open = function() {
    // reset to fadeIn animation on open
    if (this.options.animated) {
      this.modal.className = 'modal fadeIn';
    }

    // append modal to the body
    document.body.appendChild(this.modal);

    // attach events listeners
    this.modal.addEventListener('click', this);
    document.onkeyup = this.handleEvent.bind(this);

    return this;
  };

  // close modal
  Modal.prototype.close = function() {
    // clean events listeners
    this.modal.removeEventListener('click', this);
    document.onkeyup = null;

    if (this.options.animated) {
      this.modal.addEventListener('animationend', this);
      this.modal.className = 'modal fadeOut';
    } else {
      document.body.removeChild(this.modal);
      this.options.onClose();
    }

    return this;
  };

  // helper functions
  function extend(obj1, obj2) {
    for (var key in obj2)
      if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key))
        obj1[key] = obj2[key];
    return obj1;
  }

  function isFunction(fn) {
    return typeof fn === 'function';
  }













  // modal interfaces
  return {
    confirm: function(options, onConfirm, onCancel, onClose) {
      options = (typeof options === 'string') ? {
        message: options
      } : options;

      if (isFunction(onClose)) options.onClose = onClose;
      if (isFunction(onCancel)) options.onCancel = onCancel;
      if (isFunction(onConfirm)) options.onConfirm = onConfirm;

      return new Modal('confirm', options);
    },

    //PARA ALERTAS
    alert: function(options, onClose) {
      options = (typeof options === 'string') ? {
        message: options
      } : options;

      if (isFunction(onClose)) options.onClose = onClose;

      return new Modal('alert', options);
    },


    foto: function(options, onConfirm, onClose) {
      options = (typeof options === 'string') ? {
        message: options

      } : options;

      if (isFunction(onClose)) options.onClose = onClose;
      if (isFunction(onConfirm)) options.onConfirm = onConfirm;

      return new Modal('foto', options);
    },

  };
})();








/**************************************************************************************************************************************/


function m_postfoto() {
  Modal.foto({
    closeOnBlur: false,
    message: '<div class="foto/container">' +
      '<div id="drop-area">' +
      '<form class="my-form">' +
      '<p>Upload multiple files with the file dialog or by dragging and dropping images onto the dashed region</p>' +
      '<input type="file" id="fileElem" multipleaccept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">' +
      '<label class="button" for="fileElem">Select some files</label>' +
      '</form>' +
      '<progress id="progress-bar" max=100 value=0></progress>' +
      '<div id="gallery" ></div>' +
      '</div>' +

      '</div>'



  });
}












// ************************ Drag and drop ***************** //
let dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-area")

// Prevent default drag behaviors
;
['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
  document.body.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
})

// Highlight drop area when item is dragged over it
;
['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
})

;
['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
})

// Handle dropped files
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)

function preventDefaults(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
}

function highlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.add('highlight')
}

function unhighlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.remove('active')
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  var dt = e.dataTransfer
  var files = dt.files

  handleFiles(files)
}

let uploadProgress = []
let progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar')

function initializeProgress(numFiles) {
  progressBar.value = 0
  uploadProgress = []

  for (let i = numFiles; i > 0; i--) {
    uploadProgress.push(0)
  }
}

function updateProgress(fileNumber, percent) {
  uploadProgress[fileNumber] = percent
  let total = uploadProgress.reduce((tot, curr) => tot + curr, 0) / uploadProgress.length
  console.debug('update', fileNumber, percent, total)
  progressBar.value = total
}

function handleFiles(files) {
  files = [...files]
  initializeProgress(files.length)
  files.forEach(uploadFile)
  files.forEach(previewFile)
}

function previewFile(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = reader.result
    document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(img)
  }
}

function uploadFile(file, i) {
  var url = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/joezimim007/image/upload'
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  var formData = new FormData()
  xhr.open('POST', url, true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')

  // Update progress (can be used to show progress indicator)
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
  })

  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      updateProgress(i, 100) // <- Add this
    } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
      // Error. Inform the user
    }
  })

  formData.append('upload_preset', 'ujpu6gyk')
  formData.append('file', file)
  xhr.send(formData)
}
```

```css
/**
 * Modal.js
 * @author Joao Teixeira
 * @version 1.0
 * Copyright (c) Joao Teixeira
 * https://github.com/jpntex
 */

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(24, 26, 26, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: opacity;
}

.modal .modal-box {
  margin: 50px auto;
  color: #494c4c;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #263545;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 26px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 55px 20px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e4e5;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #181a1a;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-title .close-modal {
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
  top: 13px;
  right: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #aab2b2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-title .close-modal:hover {
  color: #828e8e;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-message {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e4e5;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#modal-message {
  background-color: #1a1c1c;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons:before,
.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons:after {
  clear: both;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.btn-confirm {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.btn-alert {
  width: 100%;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn+.modal-btn {
  border-left: 1px solid #e1e4e5;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn:hover {
  background-color: #e7ebed;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.red {
  color: #e34f4f;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.red:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e34f4f;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.green {
  color: #2faf45;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.green:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2faf45;
}

.modal.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease;
}

.modal.fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 0.2s forwards;
  animation: fadeOut 0.2s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #369;
}

.note {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #333;
  text-align: justify;
}

#drop-area {
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

#drop-area.highlight {
  border-color: purple;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.my-form {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#gallery {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

#fileElem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div title="Publica una foto!" class="aligbtnposts">
  <a href="#" id="uplapic" onclick="m_postfoto();" class="boton-otros">
    <div>
      <i style="    color:  #337ab7;
                                    " class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="sp_style">Foto</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Triby Entonces que hago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al cargar la página quieres obtener el elemento con id="drop-area", pero aún no existe, aparece hasta que muestras la ventana modal. Solo después de eso puedes acceder y crear los eventos necesarios.

Pasos a realizar:

1. No tratar de acceder a los elementos cuando todavía no están disponibles
2. Definir globalmente variables que pueden necesitarse en varios contextos
3. Dentro de una función se obtienen los elementos, justo después que son agregados al documento; ahí mismo se asignan eventos y se actualizan variables globales

```js
/**
 * Modal.js
 * @author Joao Teixeira
 * @version 1.0
 * Copyright (c) Joao Teixeira
 * https://github.com/jpntex
 *
 */
var Modal = (function() {
  function Modal(type, options) {

    var defaults = {
      title: '', // modal title
      message: '', // modal message
      autoOpen: true, // show modal when declared
      closeOnEscape: true, // close when escape key pressed
      closeOnBlur: true, // close when overlay is clicked
      animated: true, // animate modal

      // button options
      buttonLbl: 'OK', // main button label
      buttonClass: '', // main button class
      cancelLbl: 'Cancel', // cancel button label

      // callbacks
      onConfirm: function() {}, // callback on confirm
      onCancel: function() {}, // callback on cancel
      onClose: function() {} // callback on close
    };

    this.type = type;
    this.options = extend(defaults, options);

    // animations not supported on IE9
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 9") !== -1) {
      this.options.animated = false;
    }

    this.init();
  }

  // modal templates
  var templates = {
    modal: '<div class="modal-box">' +
      /* '<div class="modal-title">[[title]]<div class="close-modal" data-action="close">&times;</div></div>' +*/
      '<div id="modal-message" class="styles">[[message]]</div>' +
      '<div class="modal-buttons">[[buttons]]</div>' +
      '</div>',
    btn: '<div class="modal-btn" data-action="close">[[label]]</div>',
    btnAlert: '<div class="modal-btn btn-alert" data-action="close">[[label]]</div>',
    btnConfirm: '<div class="modal-btn btn-confirm [[classes]]" data-action="confirm">[[label]]</div>'
  };
  // generates the modal html from the templates given the modal's type and options
  function buildModal(type, options) {
    var modal = document.createElement('div');
    modal.className = 'modal';

    if (options.closeOnBlur) modal.setAttribute('data-action', 'close');

    var modalTmplt = templates.modal;

    // set modal animations
    if (options.animated) {
      modal.className += ' fadeIn';
    }

    modalTmplt = modalTmplt.replace('[[title]]', options.title);
    modalTmplt = modalTmplt.replace('[[message]]', options.message);

    // add buttons based on modal type
    switch (type) {
      case 'foto':
        var buttons = templates.btn.replace('[[label]]', options.cancelLbl);
        buttons += templates.btnConfirm.replace('[[label]]', options.buttonLbl).replace('[[classes]]', options.buttonClass);
        modalTmplt = modalTmplt.replace('[[buttons]]', buttons);
        break;
    }

    modal.innerHTML = modalTmplt;
    return modal;
  }

  // handle modal events
  Modal.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    var dataAction = event.target.getAttribute('data-action');

    // animation ended callback
    if (event.type === 'animationend') {
      return this.onAnimationEnd(event);
    }

    // check if 'Esc' key was pressed and close modal if set
    if (this.options.closeOnEscape) {
      if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        this.options.onCancel();
        return this.close();
      }
    }

    if (dataAction === 'close') {
      this.options.onCancel();
      return this.close();
    }

    if (dataAction === 'confirm') {
      this.options.onConfirm();
      return this.close();
    }
  };

  // animation end event handler
  Modal.prototype.onAnimationEnd = function(event) {
    this.modal.removeEventListener('animationend', this);
    document.body.removeChild(this.modal);
    this.options.onClose();
    return this;
  };

  // initialize modal creation
  Modal.prototype.init = function() {
    this.modal = buildModal(this.type, this.options);
    if (this.options.autoOpen) this.open();
  };

  // open modal
  Modal.prototype.open = function() {
    // reset to fadeIn animation on open
    if (this.options.animated) {
      this.modal.className = 'modal fadeIn';
    }

    // append modal to the body
    document.body.appendChild(this.modal);

    // attach events listeners
    this.modal.addEventListener('click', this);
    document.onkeyup = this.handleEvent.bind(this);

    return this;
  };

  // close modal
  Modal.prototype.close = function() {
    // clean events listeners
    this.modal.removeEventListener('click', this);
    document.onkeyup = null;

    if (this.options.animated) {
      this.modal.addEventListener('animationend', this);
      this.modal.className = 'modal fadeOut';
    } else {
      document.body.removeChild(this.modal);
      this.options.onClose();
    }

    return this;
  };

  // helper functions
  function extend(obj1, obj2) {
    for (var key in obj2)
      if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key))
        obj1[key] = obj2[key];
    return obj1;
  }

  function isFunction(fn) {
    return typeof fn === 'function';
  }
  // modal interfaces
  return {
    confirm: function(options, onConfirm, onCancel, onClose) {
      options = (typeof options === 'string') ? {
        message: options
      } : options;

      if (isFunction(onClose)) options.onClose = onClose;
      if (isFunction(onCancel)) options.onCancel = onCancel;
      if (isFunction(onConfirm)) options.onConfirm = onConfirm;

      return new Modal('confirm', options);
    },

    //PARA ALERTAS
    alert: function(options, onClose) {
      options = (typeof options === 'string') ? {
        message: options
      } : options;

      if (isFunction(onClose)) options.onClose = onClose;

      return new Modal('alert', options);
    },


    foto: function(options, onConfirm, onClose) {
      options = (typeof options === 'string') ? {
        message: options

      } : options;

      if (isFunction(onClose)) options.onClose = onClose;
      if (isFunction(onConfirm)) options.onConfirm = onConfirm;

      return new Modal('foto', options);
    },

  };
})();

/**************************************************************************************************************************************/


function m_postfoto() {
  Modal.foto({
    closeOnBlur: false,
    message: '<div class="foto/container">' +
      '<div id="drop-area">' +
      '<form class="my-form">' +
      '<p>Upload multiple files with the file dialog or by dragging and dropping images onto the dashed region</p>' +
      '<input type="file" id="fileElem" multipleaccept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">' +
      '<label class="button" for="fileElem">Select some files</label>' +
      '</form>' +
      '<progress id="progress-bar" max=100 value=0></progress>' +
      '<div id="gallery" ></div>' +
      '</div>' +

      '</div>'
  });
  // Se crearon los elementos, ya se pueden usar
  fotoEventos();
}
// Definir variables necesarias en contexto global
let uploadProgress = [];
let progressBar;

// Usar una función para usar elementos y asignar eventos
function fotoEventos() {
// ************************ Drag and drop ***************** //
let dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-area")

// Prevent default drag behaviors
;
['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
  document.body.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
})

// Highlight drop area when item is dragged over it
;
['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
})

;
['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
})

// Handle dropped files
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)

function preventDefaults(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
}

function highlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.add('highlight')
}

function unhighlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.remove('active')
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  var dt = e.dataTransfer
  var files = dt.files

  handleFiles(files)
}
// Actualizar variables globales
uploadProgress = []
progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar')
} // Fin de la función

function initializeProgress(numFiles) {
  progressBar.value = 0
  uploadProgress = []

  for (let i = numFiles; i > 0; i--) {
    uploadProgress.push(0)
  }
}

function updateProgress(fileNumber, percent) {
  uploadProgress[fileNumber] = percent
  let total = uploadProgress.reduce((tot, curr) => tot + curr, 0) / uploadProgress.length
  console.debug('update', fileNumber, percent, total)
  progressBar.value = total
}

function handleFiles(files) {
  files = [...files]
  initializeProgress(files.length)
  files.forEach(uploadFile)
  files.forEach(previewFile)
}

function previewFile(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = reader.result
    document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(img)
  }
}

function uploadFile(file, i) {
  var url = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/joezimim007/image/upload'
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  var formData = new FormData()
  xhr.open('POST', url, true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')

  // Update progress (can be used to show progress indicator)
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
  })

  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      updateProgress(i, 100) // <- Add this
    } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
      // Error. Inform the user
    }
  })

  formData.append('upload_preset', 'ujpu6gyk')
  formData.append('file', file)
  xhr.send(formData)
}
```

```css
/**
 * Modal.js
 * @author Joao Teixeira
 * @version 1.0
 * Copyright (c) Joao Teixeira
 * https://github.com/jpntex
 */

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(24, 26, 26, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: opacity;
}

.modal .modal-box {
  margin: 50px auto;
  color: #494c4c;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #263545;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 26px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 55px 20px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e4e5;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #181a1a;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-title .close-modal {
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
  top: 13px;
  right: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #aab2b2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-title .close-modal:hover {
  color: #828e8e;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-message {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e4e5;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#modal-message {
  background-color: #1a1c1c;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons:before,
.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons:after {
  clear: both;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.btn-confirm {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.btn-alert {
  width: 100%;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn+.modal-btn {
  border-left: 1px solid #e1e4e5;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn:hover {
  background-color: #e7ebed;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.red {
  color: #e34f4f;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.red:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e34f4f;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.green {
  color: #2faf45;
}

.modal .modal-box .modal-buttons .modal-btn.green:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2faf45;
}

.modal.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease;
}

.modal.fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 0.2s forwards;
  animation: fadeOut 0.2s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #369;
}

.note {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #333;
  text-align: justify;
}

#drop-area {
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

#drop-area.highlight {
  border-color: purple;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.my-form {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#gallery {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

#fileElem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div title="Publica una foto!" class="aligbtnposts">
  <a href="#" id="uplapic" onclick="m_postfoto();" class="boton-otros">
    <div>
      <i style="    color:  #337ab7;
                                    " class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="sp_style">Foto</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Tengo la impresión de que modificaste el código de la librería "Modal" y eso es una muy mala idea, porque te verás en serios problemas para adaptar a actualizaciones o nuevas versiones.

Comment: Si lo modifiqué, porque con esa misma librería uso varias ventanas modales más. Y no,no pienso actualizarla(la librería). Todo me funciona bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo